# How to escape colon : in rails i18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

Here is a line in the view:

```
<%= f.input :comm_date, :label => "Hello:", :as => :string %>
```

The regular i18n file has the format as:

```
  Hello : 'Aloha'
```

In i18n yml file, we want to translate the "Hello:" as, for example, "Aloha:". Can we escape the colon : by doing below?

'Hello:'  : 'Aloha:'

Or what's the right way to escape a colon?

Comment: Could you tell us *why* you want to place a colon in the translation file? Maybe we can find some workaround to avoid doing so...

Comment: We use colon : in label and would like to carry it to other language as well. Also colon also indicates that it is for label.

Comment: Well you could probably use `:label => "#{I18n.t('labels.hello')}:"` and then in your yml: `labels: hello: 'Aloha'` (with the proper indentation I can't reproduce here of course)

Comment: Generally, I'd avoid using grammar in translation file as you may need the same word multiple times in different contexts. Thus, you will end up with keys such as `date: date date_with_colon: 'date:'`. Instead you should concatenate it with your translation key in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what we did:

```
'Hello:'  : 'Aloah'
```

Just use single quote and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

The gem you are using, simple_form, as well as other similar ones such as formtastic, allow for using translation files (e.g. `en.yml`) for defining your label text.

You can see the translation file expectations from the simple_form documentation. Using your example, you'd need two translations, something like this, assuming your model is called `Communication`:

**en.yml**

```
en:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      communication:
        comm_date: "Hello:"
```

**olelo.yml**

```
olelo:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      communication:
        comm_date: "Aloha:"
```

And your view would simply be

```
<%= f.input :comm_date, :as => :string %>
```

No need to provide a value for the `:label` option.

Comment: Just checked the gem list and did not find the formatastic. Without formtastic gem, is there any way doing it?

Comment: Are you using any gems to assist in building your form? `#input` is not a method of the `FormBuilder` class.

Comment: Just use simple_form. Sorry to forget mention it.